# Select query take long times

Tags: sql-server

I want to ask how to make my query be more faster than now,
i have 2.5 Million Rows on 1 table and want to put them into tempdb before processing,

```
SELECT  a.entity_cd, a.project_no, a.divisi, a.dept, a.acc_no, a.acc_curr,a.acc_period ,a.balance_base,a.db_base,a.cr_base,a.balance_forex,a.db_forex,a.cr_forex
INTO    #trlbal
FROM    dbo.acc_trlbal a
WHERE   a.entity_cd             = @rt_entity_cd
AND     LEFT(a.acc_period, 4)   IN (@f_cyear, @f_lyear)
```

There is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[acc_trlbal](
[entity_cd] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[project_no] [char](8) NOT NULL,
[divisi] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[dept] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[acc_no] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[acc_period] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[acc_type] [numeric](1, 0) NULL,
[balance_base] [numeric](17, 2) NULL,
[balance_forex] [numeric](17, 2) NULL,
[db_base] [numeric](17, 2) NULL,
[cr_base] [numeric](17, 2) NULL,
[db_forex] [numeric](17, 2) NULL,
[cr_forex] [numeric](17, 2) NULL,
[user_entry] [char](30) NULL,
[datetime] [datetime] NULL,
[acc_name] [char](250) NULL,
[acc_curr] [char](3) NULL,
[acc_spec] [numeric](1, 0) NULL,
[update_user] [char](10) NULL,
[update_date] [datetime] NULL,
[balance_base_adj] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[balance_forex_adj] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[db_base_adj] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[cr_base_adj] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[db_forex_adj] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[cr_forex_adj] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[balance_base_adj2] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[balance_forex_adj2] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[db_base_adj2] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[cr_base_adj2] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[db_forex_adj2] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
[cr_forex_adj2] [numeric](21, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What are the data types of `acc_period`, `@f_cyear`, `@f_lyear`?. Please post the table structure of `acc_trlbal`?

Comment: I am not an sql-server expert, but you should check indexes, primary keys etc.

Comment: @FelixPamittan acc_period is varchar(6) , f_cyear = f_lyear is varchar(4)

Comment: @Ferdianto, please post the table structure together with the index.

Comment: I agree with the above, we need the structure. One little remark though. Using LEFT in the WHERE clause, will force SQL Server to evaluate it for every record in the dataset returned after  (a.entity_cd = @rt_entity_cd). So if the dataset is considerably big it may cause performance problems.

Comment: You can add a computed column on `LEFT(a.acc_period, 4)` and create an index on that.

Comment: What about the indices?

Comment: A computed column isn't strictly needed as a range query is enough, eg `acc_period between '20150101'  and '20151231'` . Storing a date as `char(6)` is a **VERY BAD IDEA** though, particularly when you can just use the `date` type for dates. Applying a function on a field is also bad, as it prevents the optimizer from using indexes. *Sometimes* the optimizer can recover from this, eg when casting `datetime` to `date`. Of course, unless there is an index on `acc_period`, no query is going to perform fast

Comment: Is there an index on `acc_period`? WIthout one, the server *has* to inspect every single row

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos acc_period is not date, just a period 'YYYYMM'

Comment: @Ferdianto split it to smallint `acc_year` and `acc_month`.

Comment: Also why are you copying all of the data to tempdb? Also the number one rule of database performance is database design. It seems your table is not well designed as others have pointed out. Indexes will help you a lot. Take advantage of SQL server's power rather than just using it as a dumping ground.